# DF.filter with empty regex result returns nosuchElement Exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Applying regex to a Data Frame like so:

```
val match2 = df.filter($"cityid" rlike "[^0-9]").first
```

This line of code is OK if something is found, but produces an error like so if nothing is found:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator
```

How can I get around this? Not sure an Option is the go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how the data frame behaves, but in plain Scala, using the head method directly is a potential problem, for example when the resulting list is empty, an exception like the one you posted is thrown.
I would suggest changing to headOption and then operate over the Option monad.
Hope that helps.
Cheers

EDIT:
As DataFrame (DataSet[T]) has not elegant way for handling a headOption similar operation, I'm proposing this solution:

```
implicit class DataSetOps(myDataSet: Dataset[T]) {
  def headOption: Option[T] = {
    myDataSet.count match {
      case size if size > 0 => Option(myDataSet.first)
      case _ => None
    }
  }
}
```

Then, you could do something like

```
val myFirstElementAsOpt: Option[T] = myDataSet.headOption
```

Comment: I have added the first on the pipeline. If I take that out then I should be in a better position.

Comment: I separated and made a check for DF.isEmpty - end of the day.

Comment: I am leaving the question for those who may benefit.

Comment: This is the clue: val result = Try(Option(df.filter($"cityid" rlike "[^0-9]").first)).toOption.flatten

Comment: @thebluephantom You are adding one unnecessary level with that approach. You could obtain the same with Try(df.filter($"cityid" rlike "[^0-9]").first).toOption

Comment: Also, I've been taking a look at the DataSet documentation (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset). It seems that there is no way to handle this operation in a more elegant fashion using Option. Maybe, you could have an implicit class wrapping the dataset which implements such handling with the help of a pattern matching.
`implicit class DataSetOps(myDataSet: Dataset[T]) {
  def headOption: Option[T] = {
    myDataSet.count match {
      case size if size > 0 => Option(myDataSet.first)
      case _ => None
    }
  }
}`

Comment: More than 1 way to skin a cat. But odd that a java failure occurs. Interesting.